# chart_type not registering in my if statement

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

The following is an excerpt from my code.

```
chart = shape.chart
    chart_type = chart.chart_type
    if not chart_type == 'COLUMN_CLUSTERED (51)':
        continue
```

When I use print(chart_type) right before the if statement, one of the outputs is exactly as written here: COLUMN_CLUSTERED (51)

This isn't making sense to me

Answer (score 0):

When you `print(chart_type)` you get the `str(chart_type)` value (or possibly the `repr(chart_type)` value). The `chart_type` value itself is an enumeration value, so you need to compare it to that enumeration member for this sort of test to work:

```
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE

if chart.chart_type == XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED:
    # --- do whatever ---
```